# Accessing Custom Web Part Attributes From Javascript Functions

Tags: development, web-part, javascript

I am developing a web part currently which has custom attributes which are defined through C#, but most of the logic has been completed using javascript. I am having trouble getting the attributes passed in to the javascript functions, as they're in a separate module.

How can I access web Part Custom attributes through javascript if that is even possible?  Below is essentially my main() function which needs to have access to the web part's attributes.

```
$.ready(webPartLoaded);

function webPartLoaded() {
    getPic();
    var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
    //myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to reference a c# object property from within an associated javascript file.

Within my webPart class I included

```
    [WebBrowsable(true),
     WebDisplayName("PicName"),
     WebDescription("Title of Picture"),
     Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
     Category("Custom Category")]
    public string TextProperty { get; set; }
```

Within the javascript I included this to reference TextProperty:

```
    console.log("object prop: <%=TextProperty%>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but at least it should work (theory):

```
protected override void CreateChildControls() {
    var script = new HtmlGenericControl 
    {
        TagName = "script",
        InnerHtml = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webPartAttributes)
    };
    script.Attributes.Add("type", "application/json");
    script.Attributes.Add("id", "data");
    Controls.Add(script);
}
```

Then in your JavaScript you can do:

```
var config = JSON.parse($('#data').text());
```

Note that I use [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), which you must add to Packages. You can alternatively use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).